# unable to get results while doing a DataFrame look in a Clojure Flambo api calls

Tags: apache-spark, clojure

I read a parquet file and and get data as RDD using Flambo api. we apply zipmap of column names and create a hash map/ Clojure map

let say my map has following values

```
[{:a 1 :b2} 
 {:a 2 :b 2}]

(:require [flambo.api :as f])
```

## core.clj

I am using

```
(f/map rdd-records (f/fn[each-rdd] 
                   (perform-calcs each-red)))
```

in perform-calcs function based on the input from map we do additional calculations, something like

## cals.clj

```
(defn perform-calcs 
[r] 
(merge r {:c (+ (:a r) (:b r))}))
```

we had a new requirement is to perform another calculation based on another DataFrame from another file. we don't want to load the file for each record so kept the code to load DataFrame out side calc and defined in commons file. this DataFrame gets loaded as part of application and can be accessible across application.

## commons.clj

```
(def another-csv-df 
     (load-file->df "file-name"))
```

## calcs.clj

```
(defn df-lookup
[r df] 
 {:d (-> 
      df (.filter (format "a = %d and b = %d" (:a r) (:b r) )    
      (.select (into [] (map #(Column. %) ["d"] )))                     
      (first)
      (.getString(0))})
```

by including this in perform-calcs function will change as follows.

```
(defn perform-calcs 
 [r] 
 (-> r  
 (merge {:c (+ (:a r) (:b r))}) 
 (df-lookup commons/another-csv-df))
```

in real I see the values on the data frame... code is working as expected with out this external call of DF with this DF look up Code it was running for long... and never complete the process

Answer (score 2):

Nested transformations like this one, are not allowed in Spark at all. You will have to rethink your approach, likely by converting RDD to `Dataset` and performing join between both.